# Unity and Hololens, how to remove the black mesh renderer?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I created a simple application which is a menu containing 4 scenes.

1. Scene 1 = using Vuforia, I replace marker with a 3D Object
2. Scene 2 = you can click on a 3D sphere
3. Scene 3 = you can click on a 3D cube
4. Scene 4 = you can click on a 3D pyramid

My main focus is the scene 1 actually.

**The problem**
When I was testing this scene in Unity, Vuforia would automatically use my webcam as a camera and I could look for marker as you can see on this picture :
[image]

Now I got my hands on the Hololens, using `Holographic Remoting Player` I keep getting this mesh on every scene I created (this picture is from Unity but I see the exact same in the Hololens) :
[image]

**What I've tried**
I looked for element using a `Mesh Renderer` but if I disable this element, then the virtual element doesn't appear anymore.

I also took a look into the MRTK Camera settings which are the following ones :
[image]

But I can't figure out how to remove this black backgrounded mesh that appears on each of my scene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, so for anyone having this issue the solution is to set the `MRTK - Spatial Awarness` display option to `Occlusion`

[image]